# Fix focus for controls on Android TV

Tags: android, flutter, focus, textfield, television

I spent much time to understand why it doesn't work, but still have no idea how to fix it.
I found this solution https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49783 , but it didn't help me.
My problem is switch doesn't change on press select button on the RC (I'm using emulator).
Steps to reproduce:

- Launch the app
- Enter some text in first text control (in my case I need to press down and up buttons to show keyboard, this is another bug, that could be cool to fix)
- Press back RC button (btw if you know how to use submit here, let me know)to hide keyboard
- Press down RC button - the focus will go to switch
- Then try to press select button (it works for the first time)
- Then return to the text field and press back and then down RC buttons
- For now switch doesn't wotk on press Select
- Press down select still doesn't work on button
- Press up - select is switching the switch and button works again!
  And the if you go to text field, then it will repeat

My sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Shortcuts(
      shortcuts: <LogicalKeySet, Intent>{
        LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.select): const ActivateIntent(),
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool switchValue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              child: Focus(
                canRequestFocus: false,
                onKey: (FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent event) {
                  if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowLeft) {
                    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!
                        .focusInDirection(TraversalDirection.left);
                  } else if (event.logicalKey ==
                      LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowRight) {
                    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!
                        .focusInDirection(TraversalDirection.right);
                  } else if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp) {
                    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!
                        .focusInDirection(TraversalDirection.up);
                  } else if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown) {
                    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!
                        .focusInDirection(TraversalDirection.down);
                  }
                  return KeyEventResult.handled;
                },
                child: TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Switch(
              value: switchValue,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  switchValue = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => print('Button pressed'),
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: const Text('Test'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.testfocus.test_focus">
<application
     android:label="test_focus"
     android:name="${applicationName}"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I'm late to this, but here's the fixed workaround for Android TV's D-pad navigation.

Please note that in the text field, we need to read the keyUp event. This is because the keyboard on Android TV seems to read the keyUp event. Therefore, if the keyDown is pressed, the keyboard will appear, and if the key is released, the keyUp event is fired, which will take input from the keyboard. That is why all of the action is done on keyUp. (took me a week to fix this issue for my app)

And we need to add a wrapper to make the text field focused for the select key press if the text field already has focus. (This is just a workaround)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Shortcuts(
      shortcuts: <LogicalKeySet, Intent>{
        LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.select): const ActivateIntent(),
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool switchValue = false;
  final FocusScopeNode node = FocusScopeNode();
  final textFocus = FocusNode();
  final textWrapper = FocusNode();
  final switchFocus = FocusNode();
  final btnNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    textFocus.addListener(_listener);
    btnNode.addListener(_listener);
    textWrapper.addListener(_listener);
    switchFocus.addListener(_listener);
    super.initState();
  }

  _listener() {
    if (textFocus.hasFocus ||
        textWrapper.hasFocus ||
        switchFocus.hasFocus ||
        btnNode.hasFocus) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textFocus.removeListener(_listener);
    btnNode.removeListener(_listener);
    textWrapper.removeListener(_listener);
    switchFocus.removeListener(_listener);
    node.dispose();
    textFocus.dispose();
    switchFocus.dispose();
    btnNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        child: FocusScope(
          autofocus: true,
          onFocusChange: (val) {
            if (val) textFocus.requestFocus();
          },
          onKey: (FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent event) {
            if (event is RawKeyUpEvent &&
                event.data is RawKeyEventDataAndroid) {
              RawKeyUpEvent rawKeyDownEvent = event;
              RawKeyEventDataAndroid rawKeyEventDataAndroid =
                  rawKeyDownEvent.data as RawKeyEventDataAndroid;

              if (rawKeyEventDataAndroid.keyCode == KEY_CENTER) {
                if (textFocus.hasFocus) {
                  textFocus.unfocus();
                  Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) {
                    textFocus.requestFocus();
                  });
                } else if (textWrapper.hasFocus) {
                  textFocus.requestFocus();
                }
              }

              if (rawKeyEventDataAndroid.keyCode == KEY_DOWN) {
                if (textWrapper.hasFocus) {
                  switchFocus.requestFocus();
                } else if (switchFocus.hasFocus) {
                  btnNode.requestFocus();
                } else {
                  textFocus.requestFocus();
                }
              }

              if (rawKeyEventDataAndroid.keyCode == KEY_UP) {
                if (btnNode.hasFocus) {
                  switchFocus.requestFocus();
                } else if (switchFocus.hasFocus) {
                  textFocus.requestFocus();
                } else {
                  btnNode.requestFocus();
                }
              }
            }
            return KeyEventResult.handled;
          },
          child: Column(
            children: [
              RawKeyboardListener(
                focusNode: textWrapper,
                child: TextField(
                  focusNode: textFocus,
                  autofocus: true,
                ),
              ),
              Shortcuts(
                shortcuts: <LogicalKeySet, Intent>{
                  LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.select):
                      const ActivateIntent(),
                  LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter):
                      const ActivateIntent(),
                },
                child: Switch(
                  value: switchValue,
                  focusNode: switchFocus,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      switchValue = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Shortcuts(
                shortcuts: <LogicalKeySet, Intent>{
                  LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.select):
                      const ActivateIntent(),
                  LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter):
                      const ActivateIntent(),
                },
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => print('Button pressed'),
                  focusNode: btnNode,
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: const Text('Test'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const int KEY_UP = 19;
const int KEY_DOWN = 20;
const int KEY_LEFT = 21;
const int KEY_RIGHT = 22;
const int KEY_CENTER = 23;
const int KEY_BACK = 4;
```

Comment: Your answer is the most correct of all solutions in stackoverflow. Thank you very much, @sai9898

Answer (score 0):

i faced the similar problem while developing tv apps using flutter.

since textfield have it's own focus i found a workaround.

i disabled input for textfield and present on screen keyboard for entering value inside textfield.

for example this one:
[image]

assign value on textfield according to button press character this would be nice workaround and more user friendly.
try to minimise user inputs while developing tv apps with flutter.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I'm finding how to resolve focuses problem and what's the cause

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing this issue while making an IPTV app for android tv whenever the focus shifted to a text field after that i was not able to use the Enter button of the TV remote but i noticed if press two times the down button and one time the up button the Enter button starts working again
The cause is still unknown it's an open issue, The only solution is to fill the text field via creating an on Screen keyboard and map values as clicked on
hope this helps